# Import excel file return null for existing data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, adodb, recordset

I'm trying to import an excel file Excel97-2003 (the first sheet only) into an Access database. for that I'm using the following code :

```
Dim cnnExcel As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsExcel As New ADODB.Recordset
With cnnExcel
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strFileSelected & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

rsExcel.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]", cnnExcel
```

All the columns in the excel file are string and have type "General" (no special format) when you open it with Excel2003) and the 3 other columns are dates.
My problem is I get null for value which exist in the cell.For exemple if the first value is string than if there's an integer in that columns it will be returned as null and vice-versa
Is there any solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Using your code, I was able to properly load data from an Excel Sheet without problem.
However, please check your SQL Query, it should be something like:

```
rsExcel.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]", cnnExcel
```

The rules for the `FROM` part as as follow:

- Query from for an entire worksheet: 
  `SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]`, note the `$`
- Query from a range:
  `SELECT * FROM [SheetName$A1:C5]`
- Query from a named range:
  `SELECT * FROM NameRange`
- Query from a worksheet that has non-alphanumerical characters:
  `SELECT * FROM ['This;is.My SheetName$']`

Code working on my machine:

```
Dim cnnExcel As Object
Dim rsExcel As Object
Set cnnExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
With cnnExcel
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\Query1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .CursorLocation = 3
    .Open
End With

rsExcel.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]", cnnExcel
Debug.Print rsExcel.RecordCount '  Prints the number of rows containing data '
Do
    Debug.Print "Col1: " & rsExcel.Fields(0) & "  - Col2: " & rsExcel.Fields(1)
    rsExcel.MoveNext
Loop While Not rsExcel.EOF
rsExcel.Close
```

**Solution 2**

You may have better luck with manipulating the Excel workbook directly.
Let's assume that you have a table `MyTable` in your Access database where you want to import in the fields `myA`, `myB` and `myC` (that have the proper datatype you expect!) the content of your Excel `Sheet 1` that has corresponding columns.

The simplified VBA code would look like this:

```
Sub ImportData(fname As String)
    Dim xlo As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim xlWs As Object
    Dim colA, colB, ColC As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim thereIsData As Boolean
    Dim row As Integer

    ' Open Excel sheet, try to re-use Excel if it is open '
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlo = GetObject("Excel.Application")
    If xlo Is Nothing Then Set xlo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Goto 0
    Set xlWb = xla.Workbooks.Open(fname)
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)  ' Sheet 1'

    ' Open table where the results will be stored '
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyTable", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do
       colA = xlWs.Cells(row, 1).Value
       colB = xlWs.Cells(row, 2).Value
       colC = xlWs.Cells(row, 3).Value
       ' We will stop at the first empty row '
       thereIsData = Not (IsBlank(colA) And IsBlank(colB) And IsBlank(colC))
       If thereIsData Then
            ' Add the Excel data to the table '
            rs.AddNew
                rs!myA = colA
                rs!myA = colB
                rs!myA = colC
            rs.Update
       End If
       row = row + 1
    Loop While thereIsData
    rs.Close
    ' Cleanup '
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set xlWs = Nothing
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    xla.DisplayAlerts = False
    xla.Quit
    Set xls = Nothing
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
' True if the argument is Nothing, Null, Empty, Missing or an empty string .  
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Public Function IsBlank(arg As Variant) As Boolean  
    Select Case VarType(arg)  
        Case vbEmpty  
            IsBlank = True  
        Case vbNull  
            IsBlank = True  
        Case vbString  
            IsBlank = (arg = vbNullString)  
        Case vbObject  
            IsBlank = (arg Is Nothing)  
        Case Else  
            IsBlank = IsMissing(arg)  
    End Select  
End Function
```

Comment: I don't if i can use this method, I'm using Windows7/Access2010 and the application will run on WindowsXP/Access2003 and the Excel file should be Excel97-2003. My problem is that i get null for values that exist really on the excel cell

Comment: This will work with any version of Access and Excel. It doesn't use or rely on specific libraries. Just try it and see.

Comment: With my code i'm able to read data in the excel file. No prblem in the query. If the column contains 
A
B
C
4
my code read A,B,C but the rsExcel.Fields(1).Value return null while there's a 4 there.

Comment: with the second solution i got "Automation error on line " Set xlo = GetObject("Excel.Application")"

Comment: I updated the code to avoid the error. Otherwise, using rsExcel.Fields(1), I'm getting the values without problem. Are you sure you are calling rsExcel.MoveNext to move to the next row in your loop?

Comment: Absolutly!
But did you used mixed data?

Comment: This works for me!
I'm wondering if there's a method  to read a whole row at a time?

Comment: If this worked for you, then please mark the answer so others may find this help more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to convert any numbers in your Excel data to text format (numbers formatted as text have a green triangle in the corner by default which can be suppressed using the error checking options). There are two ways I know of to do this, one for single columns and one for larger ranges:

Method 1) Select a single column, then choose Data Tab > Text to Columns click next twice, choose the Text option in the third step then click Finish.

Method 2) Copy the whole table or sheet then choose Format cells and click Text for the Number Format. Now you can paste as text either by clicking the icon on the office clipboard or by pasting the table to notepad and copying and pasting back to Excel. (The office clipboard can be activated by clicking the arrow at the bottom right of the clipboard section on the home tab)

Comment: My excel file does not contain any text format actually.It should be possible to read the values of the cell as Text

Comment: From your description it seems that you have a table in Excel formatted in General number format with a mixture of data types (text, numbers, dates). Access requires each column to be a single data type, if a column is mainly text but with some numbers as well, the numbers will be returned as null - it will not convert them for you. When I have had this issue I have found the simplest way around is to convert the columns in Excel to text format as above and data has imported OK. You can test this by copying and pasting the table into the Access database window.